# Change an iframe's src from another html file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Well, I have my `radio elements` that update an `iFrame` with `js code`; and that works fine.

Then I have my `button` below that creates an `iFrame` in a `HTML Division` that contains a bunch o' `buttons` in a list, my aim is to click one of these `buttons` in the `iFrame` then have that button to update the above `iFrame` (the one controlled by the `radio's`).

How is this possible, can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Note: I've tried using `<link rel="import" href="parentpage.html">` to import its ID's (if it does that?) then tried using `JS` to update it that way, to no avail.

What it looks like (layout wise)![image: layout]

Comment: You can't access elements of other iframes, but you could load data via ajax for example, or make an refreshing system which checks a database every n seconds to see which of the buttons is currently pressed.

Comment: Looks like i was wrong, I found a way to do this without ajax, see my answer below :)

Comment: Is there a way to do this with PHP? I'm inexperienced with PHP, and I am just curious :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the frames are in the same domain, this can be done like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Main Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             var change_iframe1_src = function(new_src) {
                 $("#iframe1").attr('src', new_src);
             }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- frame for which we will change src attribute -->
        <iframe id="iframe1" src="" width="400" height="200" border="1"></iframe>        
        <!-- frame which includes your iframe2 with the buttons-->
        <iframe src="iframe.html" width="200" height="200" border="1"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now in the iframe2 file attach a click handler for your buttons that should change the src attribute of the iframe1 by calling a function defined in the main page.

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>iFrame 2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("button").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                // call function in a parent frame - IMPORTANT LINE BELOW :)
                parent.window.change_iframe1_src(this.rel);
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button rel="iframe3.html">Change iframe src to iframe3.html</button>
    <button rel="iframe4.html">Change iframe src to iframe4.html</button>
</body>
```

The links in the iframe 2 page call the function which is defined in the parent window (the main page / the window which embeded the iframe2 page itself). That function (change_iframe1_src in this example) takes one argument which is a new url.
The src attribute of the frame #iframe1 (your first frame) will be changed to this url.

Again, this works as long as all the frames are in the same domain.

Hope it helped :)  [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7228509/3582159)

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do so is to get the button inside the iframe and set the event onclick like this

```
$(document.getElementById('iFrame2').contentWindow.document.getElementById("iFrame2Button")).click
   (function () 
   { 
          $("#iFrame1").attr('src','tests.php'); 
   })
```

Comment: With this method, it seems to just refresh the iFrame containing the buttons and not replace the frame that I want to changed... Hm. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: is seems to refresh the iFrame containing the buttons if you change the src attribute to the same url of the iframe. and don't be confused by the ids ( iFrame2 , iFrame1 , iFrame2Button )

Comment: If you don't mind, could you elaborate further please:)

Comment: Let's say you want to change the url of iFrame1, it's id should be `id="iFrame1"` , the iframe 2 contains a button , the id of the iframe 2 should be `id="iFrame2"` and the id of the button inside iframe2 should be `id="iFrame2Button"` ... now the code I posted will work perfectly, you just have to change `test.php`  on `$("#iFrame1").attr('src','tests.php');` by the url of the page that your iFrame1 will include.

Comment: `$(document.getElementById("iframe2").contentWindow.document.getElementById("iframe2button")).click
    (function () { 
        $("#iframe1").attr("src", url); 
    });`

Is what I have :)

Comment: if this code doesn't work for you , you should correct your html code ... don't forget that iframes should contain pages from the same domain , otherwise you can't do that

Comment: Yes, yes; Same Origin policy :D But my code is all on localhost at the moment, so shouldn't it all be on the same domain then? Hm.

Comment: if your code is in localhost, your iframes should contrain pages from localhost