# How do I change 'src' of an iframe from another page onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two html pages `1.html` and `2.html`.

I have two buttons on `1.html`.

- one button links to Google
- one button links to Facebook

I have an `iframe` in `2.html`.

How do I change the `iframe src` on `2.html` by clicking on a button on `1.html`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an iframe's src from another html file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873546/change-an-iframes-src-from-another-html-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script>
            function changeSrc(loc) {
                document.getElementById('iframeId').src = loc;
            }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="changeSrc('http://en.wikipedia.org')">Wikipedia</button>
        <button onclick="changeSrc('http://www.bing.com')">Bing</button>
        <iframe id="iframeId" src="" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try following...

```
<button onclick="return (function(){
   var _iframe = document.getElementById('iFrameId');
   _iframe.src = '1.html';
})();">Page 1</button>

<button onclick="return (function(){
   var _iframe = document.getElementById('iFrameId');
   _iframe.src = '2.html';
})();">Page 2</button>
```

Comment: it doesnt change iframe src on the 2.html

Comment: are both page 1 and 2 is part of single page ??

Comment: no click a link on page 1 to change iframe src on page 2

Comment: You can then use php here to pass data to page 2 and set src there

Comment: but am using django can i do it with python too ?

Comment: you can send data as in link also using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

This answer was created before SO's change to more secure policies, I have updated the demo by adding a "s" to http of the src. Keep in mind that any interaction with an iframe is subject to security measures of both the website of the iframe and the website within the iframe.

You can use HTML and you don't need CSS or JS/jQ:

- Create an `<a>` with the `href` with the url of desired destination.
- Add a `target` attribute with the value of the iframe's `name` attribute.

BTW, Google and Facebook busts iframes, so the demonstrations have different sites.

## [<kbd>**PLUNKER**</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/9vQKISuGbS4GH6MmXXgk/)

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    iframe {
      width: 97vw;
      height: 65vh;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <fieldset>
    <button><a href='https://plainjs.com' target='ifrm1'>PlainJS</a>
    </button>
  </fieldset>
  <iframe name='ifrm1' src='about:blank'></iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Kukeltje I believe JSFiddle.net doesn't do well with iframes in certain circumstances, review the demo in the [plunker link I provided](http://embed.plnkr.co/9vQKISuGbS4GH6MmXXgk/). This answer was created before SO's change to more secure policies, I have updated the demo by adding a "s" to `http` of the `src`.  Keep in mind that any interaction with an iframe is subject to security measures of both the website of the iframe and the website within the iframe.