# Change 'src' of an iframe from another page

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have a page 'A' which has link to another page 'B'.
On page 'B' there is an iframe. I have no control on page 'B' i.e. I cannot edit  page 'B'. Ask is to change 'src' of an iframe on page 'B' on click of link on page 'A'.

Comment: Simple answer, you can't do nothing if you have no control of B.
You can only change value of iframe if it's on same domain, else no way.

Comment: Instead of linking to the page, you *could* load the page and modify it before displaying it. This would most likely need to be done on the server, unless there are appropriate CORS headers. Of course, this might open the door to whole range of other issues (both technical and legal).

Comment: Also, do you have control over the original contents of the iframe? If so, you could simply do a redirect...

Comment: Check it: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226939/how-to-change-iframe-src-from-another-page) It works for me

Answer (score 0):

All else being equal: No.

Page B could be written so that it takes some external input (such as a query string on its URL) which it uses to set different values for the `src` attribute of the `iframe` … but that isn't typical so you'd probably have to modify B (which you said you can't do) in order to create such a feature.

Comment: I could have gone with the query string approach but again I cannot modify page 'B'

Comment: @sanket — I acknowledged that in the answer. The first part still stands: No.